# CSS not updating after Heroku deployments

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have read other questions with similar issues and tried their fixes to no avail

I have a 3.2.14 Rails app, where when I make changes in one CSS file followed by pushing the code to heroku, the specific CSS changes do not update. I have already tried:

```
-Verified that my git status is clean.
-- Tested in New Google Incognito Window for cache check
-- heroku restart
-- rake assets:precompile before deploying
-- Followed these instructions to specifically precompile in production environment
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline
-- Ran: 
bundle exec rake tmp:clear
bundle exec rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=production
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Thanks for reading. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you post your config/environments/production.rb & Gemfile

Comment: Have you made sure your app is serving static assets? (as per production.rb) ?

Comment: Also, if you right-click > view source, do you see valid files in the header?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have solved your problem by now. However I believe trying these commands in the following order would work.

```
$bundle exec rake assets:precompile
$git add . 
$git commit -m "msg" 
$git push heroku master
```